# Switch left & right alt keys

Tags: keyboard-layout

I just installed Arch Linux on my Macbook Air, and I've been using Macs for so long that my PC keyboard muscle memory has all but deteriorated. In Mac when I type "special" chars like $, @ etc. I use the left option (or alt) key to do that. Now in linux (or Windows, for that matter) the right alt key gives me those chars and left alt is just a modifier key. Is there a way to switch those two?

xmodmap -pm output:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily completely remap you entire keyboard, including all "special" keys. If your Arch Linux uses Wayland, you need `xkb` (which requires some reading), if it uses X, play around with `xmodmap`, and load your layout on session login.

Google a bit, there are plenty of tutorials.

Comment: Yup, been there, done that. I can only find examples of switching alt & cmd or bunch of others, but for the life of me, just can't seem to figure out how to switch left & right alt.

Comment: It would help if you could say if which method you are using: `xmodmap` or `xkb`. Then I can add details.

Comment: I've tried both, but most recently using xmodmap. I tried switching the definitions for Left Alt & Right Alt like this:

    keycode 64 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
    keycode 108 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L

And I did at some point manage to map right alt as left alt, but couldn't get the special characters to work on the left alt.

Comment: Please edit question with output of `xmodmap -pm`, to see if your current setup uses really ISO_Level3_Shift, or Mode_switch, or possibly both.

Comment: Edited the original question and added the outpu